# knockout.js - selecting & printing an object

Tags: knockout.js

Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cLm3evns/ .

I want the `newproduct` to be inserted to `selectedProduct` so I can print its contents.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see following updated fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/cLm3evns/1/.

You forgot following thing in your model.

```
var self = this.
```